# Popup window on youtube api event

Tags: jquery, youtube-api, dom-events, simplemodal

I'm using simplemodal to popup a modal window. I've tested the modal window functionality and it is all working fine.

I have a hidden div element:

```
        <div id="form-box" class="form-box" style="display:none;">
        <div class="form-crop">
        <script type="text/javascript"         src="https://releasetechnique.infusionsoft.com/app/form/iframe/84f82828ea34c2a633bbe0a87560586c"></script>
        </div>
        </div>
```

this pops up just fine if as  I tested it with a timer.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    setInterval(update, 1000);
    });

    function update() {
    $("#form-box").modal();
    }
    </script>
```

Now what I'm trying to do is grab the information from Youtube's API, which I've successfully tested with the following:

```
    function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
        $ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
        $ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
    }

    function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
        alert("Player's new state: " + newState);


    }
```

This works as intended. It returns the current player state, and any time the player state is changed the alert lets me know.

Now, what I want to do is popup the modal window, when the player state is equal to 0. 0 means the player has stopped. So basically, 0 is returned as newstate once the Youtube video finishes playing.

I've tried the following and can't get it to work. Any suggestions?

```
    function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
        $ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
        $ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
    }

    function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
        if(newstate === 0) {
            $("#form-box").modal(); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$("form-box").modal();` should be `$("#form-box").modal();`
2. Are you sure `newState` is a number? If not, you might want to use `==` instead of `===`
3. Remove other unused jQuery plugins in your page. They could be causing conflicts.

Comment: i must have just edited the # as i noticed that too. im not sure its a number ill try == instead and let you know

Comment: tested with == instead of === and still isnt firing.

Comment: what does console.log() say `newState`'s value is?

Comment: says not defined... not sure why

Comment: what was the value of `newState` when the content of `onytplayerStateChange()` was still `alert("Player's new state: " + newState);`?

Comment: i just changed it back to the alert and it still returned undefined

Comment: this has been driving me nuts for over a week!

Comment: could you turn your `alert` into `console.log()` please?

Comment: i tested, and when the video ended, console.log said `Player's new state: 0`. could you change the contents of your `if(newstate === 0) {}` to `alert('video finished');`

Comment: that works so it must be something with calling the simple modal function...i know simplemodal worksbecause i tested that. i can show you on the update function if you want to verify

Comment: ok change it back to `$("#form-box").modal();`. are you using fancybox? if not, remove it from your code. it could be causing conflicts

Comment: BOOM! it must have been fancy box. i dont think it was actually being used anywhere. however i didnt design the page so im not sure.

Comment: weird though. i left fancy box and tested again and it still works haha

Comment: thanks for your help ma, much appreciated. who knows what it was i swear i tried all of this stuff. now i can  finally relax, thing has been driving me crazy!

Comment: i refreshed the page, the one where you re-added fancybox, and the simplemodal doesn't show up when the video ends. (by the way, change `alert` to `console.log` cos it's annoying lol)